How to Add SSL Certificate in IOS in flutter app
I have Flutter project in which I'm using webview_flutter. Now for Android app's SSL handshake failed error I added SSL certificate in Android part of project so it's working fine in android app but I don't know how can I add SSL certificate in IOS part of my flutter project.
So any lead would be great help.
If anyone can suggest how can I SSL certificate in IOS or how can I bypass ssl certificate error that would be great help.
I have added this code in my info.plist still facing issues:
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>*.mantratecapp.com</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
                <string>TLSv1.2</string>
                <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>


Have you tried adding this code to the Info.plist file yet?
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
 <dict>
      <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
     <true/>
 </dict>


I have added that line.
